# Outputting an image in JavaScript onto a hangman game

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a hangman game and I have to output images, when the users lives get down from 7-0.
I have put this code into my javascript , however it only outputs the if(lives ==8) image.
Unfortunality  it does not seem to work at all ?

I am very new to javascript and when I have read the other answers, I have found them hard to understand.

The fact that it doesn't output , does this mean I have an error in my code somewhere. ?

```
    function setup() {

    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    lives = 8;
    var words = ["ayeupmeducks", "pieceofcake", "bullinachinashop", "hangfire","greeneyedmonster",       "hairraising","bringhomethebacon","adiamondintherough","onceinabluemoon","afootinthedoor","bitethebullet"];
    messages = {
        win: 'Congratulations you have won the game of Hangman!',
        lose: 'You have been Hanged !!',
        guessed: ' already guessed, please try again...',
        validLetter: 'Please enter a letter from A-Z'
         };

     var getHint = document.getElementById("hint");
     var showClue = document.getElementById("clue");
     getHint.onclick = function() {
     hints = 
    ["Stoke Greeting","Saying Something is Easy", "Very Clumsy","delaying something for a minute", "When you are jealous of something","Something is frightening", "Earn Money", "Rough Exterior however has some potential", "When something rarely happens", "When you have succeeded/ getting yourself known by a company","accepting something , when you do not want to"];
    var hintIndex = words
    showClue.innerHTML = "Clue: - " +  hints [idx];
     };
    gussedLetter = matchedLetter = '';
    numberofMatchedLetters = 0;

  /* This chooses the word which will be displayed on the page */
     idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
     currentWord = words[idx];
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    message = document.getElementById("message");
    guessInput = document.getElementById("letter");
    message.innerHTML = 'You have ' + lives + ' lives remaining';
    output.innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("letter").value = '';

    guessButton = document.getElementById("guess");
    guessInput.style.display = 'inline';
    guessButton.style.display = 'inline';

    letters = document.getElementById("letters");
    letters.innerHTML = '<li class="current-word">Current word:</li>';
    var letter, i;
    for (i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
    /*  returns the character at the specified index in a string.*/
        letter = '<li class="letter letter' + currentWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + '">' + currentWord.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + '</li>';
    /*  inserts the results node into Dom at the correct place, The BeforeEnd- inside the element, after its last child.*/
        letters.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', letter);
    }
}
function gameOver(win) {
    if (win) {
        output.innerHTML = messages.win;
        output.classList.add('win');
    } else {
        output.innerHTML = messages.lose;
        output.classList.add('error');

    } 
    guessInput.style.display = guessButton.style.display = 'none';
    guessInput.value = '';
}
window.onload = setup();
document.getElementById("restart").onclick = setup;
     guessInput.onclick = function () {
     this.value = '';
};

    document.getElementById('hangman').onsubmit = function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    output.innerHTML = '';
    output.classList.remove('error', 'warning');
    guess = guessInput.value;

    if (guess) {
        if (alphabet.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
        if ((matchedLetter && matchedLetter.indexOf(guess) > -1) || (gussedLetter && gussedLetter.indexOf(guess) > -1)) {
                output.innerHTML = '"' + guess.toUpperCase() + '"' + messages.guessed;
               output.classList.add("warning");
            }
            else if (currentWord.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
             var lettersToShow;
              lettersToShow = document.querySelectorAll(".letter" + guess.toUpperCase());
              for (var i = 0; i < lettersToShow.length; i++) {
                    lettersToShow[i].classList.add("correct");
                }


                for (var j = 0; j < currentWord.length; j++) {
                    if (currentWord.charAt(j) === guess) {
                        numberofMatchedLetters += 1;
                    }
                }
                matchedLetter += guess;
                if (numberofMatchedLetters === currentWord.length) {
                    gameOver(true);
               }
            }
            else {
                gussedLetter += guess;
                lives--;
                message.innerHTML = 'You have ' + lives + ' lives remaining';
                if (lives === 0) gameOver();
                               }
        }
        else {
            output.classList.add('error');
            output.innerHTML = messages.validLetter;
        }
    }
    else {
        output.classList.add('error');
        output.innerHTML = messages.validLetter;
    }
    return false;
    };

   var x = document.createElement("IMG");
   if (lives==8){
           x.setAttribute("src", "Hangman-0.png");
           x.setAttribute("width", "304");
           x.setAttribute("height", "228");
           x.setAttribute("alt", "Hangman");
           document.body.appendChild(x);}
  if (lives==7){
           x.setAttribute("src", "Hangman-1.png");
           x.setAttribute("width", "304");
           x.setAttribute("height", "228");
           x.setAttribute("alt", "Hangman");
           document.body.appendChild(x);}
```

Comment: how are you updating `lives`?

Comment: lives--; - so if a wrong letter has been guessed - the lives which have the value of 8 reduce by one

Comment: Can you show your full code in that case?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at you code, you can simplify a lot - each image has the same height, width, and alt, so you can move all of that out of the function.  Also, assuming the `src` attribute is just a number that is incrementing, you can instead do something like:

```
var num_lives = 8;
var lives_left = 8;
function guess() {
    lives_left--;
    x.setAttribute('src', 'Hangman-' + (num_lives - lives_left) + '.png');
}
```

So, as a working example, your code would basically be:

```js
var url = 'https://www.oligalma.com/downloads/images/hangman/files/';
const num_lives = 10;
var lives = 10;
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("width", "304");
x.setAttribute("height", "228");
x.setAttribute("alt", "Hangman");
x.setAttribute("src", url + (num_lives - lives) + '.jpg');
document.body.appendChild(x);

function change() {
    lives--;
    if (lives < 0) {
        lives = num_lives;
    }
    x.setAttribute("src", url + (num_lives - lives) + '.jpg');
    
}
```

```html
<button onClick="change()">Guess</button>
```